# Join on multiple conditions with condition in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have a table named 'files' with following columns:

- id (integer pk)
- file_name (varchar not null)
- version (varchar not null)
- size (integer not null)
- sha1 (varchar)
- has_sha1 (boolean not null)

And the current SQL query is to compare two version's file size as following:

```
SELECT 
    filesA.fileName AS fileName, 
    filesA.size AS sizeA, filesB.size AS sizeB, 
    filesA.version AS versionA, filesB.version AS versionB
FROM
    (SELECT * 
     FROM files 
     WHERE version = '1.0') filesA
FULL JOIN
    (SELECT * 
     FROM files 
     WHERE version = '1.1') filesB ON filesA.file_name = filesB.file_name;
```

The problem is that some 'file_name' are the same in two versions and it should be identified/compared by 'sha1' column but other 'file_name' should still identified/compared by 'file_name' column and has NULL value in 'sha1' column. 'has_sha1' column can tell if a file should be identified/compared by 'sha1' or not.

I tried to add an additional `ON` clause like this: `AND filesA.sha1 = filesB.sha1` like this:

```
SELECT 
    filesA.fileName AS fileName, 
    filesA.size AS sizeA, filesB.size AS sizeB, 
    filesA.version AS versionA, filesB.version AS versionB
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM files WHERE version = '1.0') filesA
FULL JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM files WHERE version = '1.1') filesB
        ON filesA.file_name = filesB.file_name
        AND filesA.sha1 = filesB.sha1;
```

But it is not working.

I expecting files has true in 'has_sha1' column can be identified(compared) by 'sha1' column and others can be identified (compared) by 'file_name' column. Is there any way to identify conditionally in one SQL?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why the [tag:java] tag? There is (apparently) no Java code involved - just pure SQL

Comment: mysql does not have full join..some sql dialects do, are you looking for a generic sql solution or for a specific dialect?

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon im using postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression as join condition:

```
.. ON CASE WHEN filesa.has_sha1 AND filesb.has_sha1
           THEN filesa.hsa1 = filesb.sha1
           ELSE filesa.file_name = filesb.file_name
      END
```

I expect that both sides of the join are fairly small. Otherwise, you cannot expect great performance, since this can only be calculated as a nested loop join.